# Notification click onNewIntent not called

Tags: android, notifications

This is how activity declared in `Manifest`

```
<activity
    android:name=".view.activity.HomeActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And this is how I generate the notification

```
val notificationManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val channel = NotificationChannel("1", "MyApp", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
}

val notificationLayout = RemoteViews(applicationContext.packageName, R.layout.notification_view)
val notificationLayoutExpanded = RemoteViews(applicationContext.packageName, R.layout.notification_big_view)
updateLayout(notificationLayout, notificationLayoutExpanded, data)

val intent = Intent(applicationContext, HomeActivity::class.java).apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
    putExtra("Id", Id)
}
val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "1")
        .setContentTitle("MyApp")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.circle)
        .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
        .setCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)

notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build())
```

But when I tap on the notification `onNewIntent` called sometimes only (Maybe if app in open state, I can't guess correctly).

Comment: `onNewIntent` is only called if the activity is already open, It won't be called if the Activity is not open.

Comment: @ZohaibAmir.. Then how to resolve this..

Comment: your activity does start right?

Comment: you should do the same thing in `onCreate()` as you do in `onNewIntent()`

Comment: where you place `onNewIntent()` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe I overrided in activity

Comment: @Gunaseelan inside `onCreate()` use `getIntent` and see if the notification parameters are passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onNewIntent` is only called if the activity is already open, It won't be called if the Activity is not open.

This means that if your activity was closed, it will start normally and `onCreate` will be called. 
You can pass a flag in your intent that tells your Activity that it was started from notification, then you find that flag in your `onCreate` and if it exists, you call the same functions as you did in `onNewIntent()`:

```java
val intent = Intent(applicationContext, HomeActivity::class.java).apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
    putExtra("Id", Id)
    putExtra("notificationIntent", true);
}
```

And in your `OnCreate()`:

```java
boolean isNotificationIntent = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("notificationIntent", false);

if(isNotificationIntent){
   DoSameWorkAsOnNewIntent();
}
```